# Word 2010 Formatting Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to format my report in following way using automatic TOC

Table of Contents

> Chapter 1: Introduction to PHP ..................... 1

```
   1.1. Introduction .............................. 1
   1.2. Variables ................................. 5
```

> Chapter 2: Loops ................................... 15

Contents

### Chapter 1

### Introduction to PHP

Introduction (Sub heading)

Everything is perfect except formating the TOC. Currently the table of contents looks like

```
Table of Contents
   Chapter 1: ......................................... 1
   Introduction to PHP ................................ 1
       1.1. Introduction .............................. 1
```

How do I format this table of content to look like the one is on the top.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just edit it yourself in that little blue thingy or there should be an option to convert it to text.

Comment: Yes, I can do it but then when I update it next time all changes will be lost :)

Comment: Ah yes...I remember that from when I tried that. Best idea is to finish your report before you do any formatting crap...

Comment: I don't see how this could work, if you update your table, the changes will be lost

Comment: This is a mere workaround, not a solution, @Wayne Johnston's solution is Ok though.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the table styles. Each time you generate the Table of Contents (TOC) it will use the new style.

- Select the References Tab and click Table of Contents
- Select the Insert New Table of Contents from the bottom of the menu.
- Choose the Format that's the best match for what you want as a starting point
- If you want to make more changes, click Modify
- Select the level of the TOC that you want to change; there is one for each level in the TOC
- Click Modify (on the second dialog)
- Change the formatting of the style. You can do a lot from this dialog, but if you need more control, click the Format button at the bottom.
- Click OK to save the changes.
- Repeat for other levels of the TOC.

Later on if you want to modify the styles, you can do this from the Styles dialog. Press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S or click on the thingy in the lower right corner of the Styles tool on the Home tab.

If you wind up creating a lot of documents where you want the same styles, you can create your own template file. You can save styles in a template file so when you create a new document all those styles will be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution, you will have numbers on both heading and in table of contents.

Before:

**Content of document:**

```
Heading_1
  Heading_2
    bla bla bla
    bla bla bla

  Heading_2
    bla bla bla
    bla bla bla
```

**TOC:**

```
TABLE OF CONTENTS
Heading_1..........1
  Heading_2........1
  Heading_2........2
```

Go to `home` > click the little arrow next to the `multi-level list icon` > choose a style under `List library`.

Then go to `References` > `Table of contents` > `Automatic table 1 or 2`, or refresh your table.

You should have this:

**Content of document:**

```
1 Heading_1
  1.1 Heading_2
    bla bla bla
    bla bla bla

  1.2 Heading_2
    bla bla bla
    bla bla bla
```

**TOC:**

```
TABLE OF CONTENTS
1 Heading_1...........1
  1.1 Heading_2.......1
  1.2 Heading_2.......2
```

Not that if your table of contents is numbered (so your first heading_1 starts at 2), you can do the folowing:

select the `TABLE OF CONTENT` text in your TOC > right click > unselect the `numbering icon`. Then update your table.