# Easy Update "Table of Contents" feature in Microsoft Word 2007 VS. Microsoft word 2010

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I am currently working on a document that was written using Microsoft Word 2007 and I am also using Microsoft Word 2007 to update the document.  It is just the way of the workplace I am now in.

I have noticed that the feature of adding nested headers ("subheaders" perhaps) does not work the same as I remember it did with Microsoft Word 2010.  Since I am not the original author of the document, I am not sure if the table of contents was set up the right way.  So my first question is: How do I see if the table of contents was set up properly in Microsoft Word 2007 to allow automatic updates whenever a subheader is added to the text.  There seems to be a number of other things going on with the document that do not seem right.  But maybe if we fix this problem first the other issues will dissolve or be lessened.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a table of contents (and providing that you use the "header" styles defined in office) you need to manually refresh the table of contents, rather then have it all be automatic.

First port of call to make sure that the table of contents is set up correctly is to check the styles applied to the headers that do appear in the table. Make sure you use the same styles to headings and subheadings you add, because you can define custom styles and use them for the headers.

Then you can select the table and in the "reference" tab, click "update table"

If that doesn't change the table at all, then it would point to the table being manually created, and you'd need to generate the table of contents properly.

There is an article about tables of contents on the office section of the microsoft site available [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-table-of-contents-HP001225372.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/183495/word-2010-formatting-table-of-contents/190226#190226) discusses how to modify the table of contents style. Despite the title, the information also applies to Word 2007. As Trezoid mentions the table of contents has to be manually refreshed to include the new content.