# Table of Contents Outside of Margin

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

I currently have an automatic table of contents generated for a report I have written. All of the headings in the report are formatted correctly and all indent as expected on the TOC.

However, the Header 1 styled entries in the TOC extend past the right margin. The effect I have is:

```
1.0  Introduction (Heading 1).............2
   1.1  Next (Header 2)..............4
        1.1.1   Next (Header 2)......5
        1.1.2   Final (Header 2).....6
2.0  Introduction (Heading 1).............7
   2.1  Next (Header 2)..............8
        2.1.1   Next (Header 2)......8
        2.1.2   Final (Header 2).....9
```

I have checked everything, yet I can't seem to find the issue. The heading 1 style actually goes over the defined word margin where as all the other headings fit fine as shown above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word 2010 Formatting Table of Contents](http://superuser.com/questions/183495/word-2010-formatting-table-of-contents)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may need to clear the tab stops on the TOC field levels.  I had this problem when I changed the page widths and changed the number of levels in the table of contents.

1. Right Click your Table of Contents and select `Edit Field` then
   scroll down to `TOC` and click the `Table of Contents` button.
2. In the Table of Contents window, click the `Modify` button in the
   bottom right corner.
3. In the new Style window click `TOC 1` and then select `Modify`
4. In the Modify Style window click the `Format` button in the bottom left the select `Tabs...`
5. Click either `Clear all` or delete the tabs you do not want.  Now click OK to accept, then OK again in the Modify Style window.
6. Repeat 3-5 for each of the levels of TOC entries you are using, by the looks of it you want `TOC 1`, `TOC 2` and `TOC 3`
7. Click OK until you are back at your document and have accepted the request to update the Table of Contents.

All being well you should now have all your entries properly right aligned.

Comment: Wish I could vote you twice :D

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the page layout on the top left of your word document and choose normal margins or any margins your document is, your table of contents get in the margins.